# how can I view all IP's of devices connected to a wlan?

Tags: linux, networking

so, I am using vmware with Linux Ubuntu, please I need to know how can I view all PC's and devices connected together in my LAN or WLAN with their IP's

Comment: Just the PCs? Not mobile devices? Not smart devices? Not printers?

Comment: well also, like all devices connected to the network

Comment: Well, I would suggest typing 192.168.1.1 in the address bar of any web browsers(and hit Enter) to visit your modem/router page...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want something quick, most routers let you look at the current DHCP leases.  Log in to your router and check.  Anything that's requested a DHCP lease from your home router is something that's likely online or has been recently.  This isn't a 100% guarantee of everything on your network but might be good enough.

If you want to scan your network, the tool you want to learn about is `nmap`.  It's installable on Ubuntu (if it's not there already) with a command like `apt-get install nmap`.

[Here's a good article](https://www.redhat.com/sysadmin/quick-nmap-inventory) that can get you started on using it.

Comment: thnx...I am starting a small course in nmap, but the insructor just sarted by nmap [ip for the victim] thats how i woundered then how can I know the IP of victim after all... the article sounds usefull.. i will check..the problem with router thing is that I am using VMware that has a different IP from the Win PC that is installed on , now when I ping in the Vmware ubuntu , the win IP or IP of my phone that is connected to the network it doesn't ping, so I wanted to check how does the vmware see the IP's of the network

Answer (score 1):

LawrenceC has provided a good answer for when you have access to the leases of the DHCP server or when hosts are responding to the requests created by `nmap`. Alternatively, you could look at the ARP table where link-layer (MAC) addresses are related to network-layer addresses (e.g. IPv4).
The `arp` command is already installed on many Linux distributions. You can run `arp -a` to print the ARP table.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote arp -a in ubuntu vmware it showed :
localhost (192.168.198.2) at 00:50:56:f9:80:be [ether] on ens33

I wrote it on the powershell of the win10 where the vmware is installed :
Schnittstelle: 192.168.178.29 --- 0x8
Internetadresse       Physische Adresse     Typ
192.168.178.1         e8-df-70-b7-74-d5     dynamisch
192.168.178.43        48-6d-bb-46-6a-6f     dynamisch
192.168.178.255       ff-ff-ff-ff-ff-ff     statisch
224.0.0.2             01-00-5e-00-00-02     statisch
224.0.0.22            01-00-5e-00-00-16     statisch
224.0.0.251           01-00-5e-00-00-fb     statisch
224.0.0.252           01-00-5e-00-00-fc     statisch
239.255.255.250       01-00-5e-7f-ff-fa     statisch
255.255.255.255       ff-ff-ff-ff-ff-ff     statisch

Schnittstelle: 192.168.56.1 --- 0xb
Internetadresse       Physische Adresse     Typ
192.168.56.255        ff-ff-ff-ff-ff-ff     statisch
224.0.0.2             01-00-5e-00-00-02     statisch
224.0.0.22            01-00-5e-00-00-16     statisch
224.0.0.251           01-00-5e-00-00-fb     statisch
224.0.0.252           01-00-5e-00-00-fc     statisch
239.255.255.250       01-00-5e-7f-ff-fa     statisch
255.255.255.255       ff-ff-ff-ff-ff-ff     statisch

Schnittstelle: 192.168.24.1 --- 0xd
Internetadresse       Physische Adresse     Typ
192.168.24.254        00-50-56-e6-65-51     dynamisch
192.168.24.255        ff-ff-ff-ff-ff-ff     statisch
224.0.0.2             01-00-5e-00-00-02     statisch
224.0.0.22            01-00-5e-00-00-16     statisch
224.0.0.251           01-00-5e-00-00-fb     statisch
224.0.0.252           01-00-5e-00-00-fc     statisch
239.255.255.250       01-00-5e-7f-ff-fa     statisch
255.255.255.255       ff-ff-ff-ff-ff-ff     statisch

however,in this table I can't find the IP of my phone or my VMware connection.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u6YTr.jpg)